# NodeJS anyDB lost connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, sqlanydb

Hello i have made a chat app in nodejs and it works fine on my machine but when i try it on my vps it always stops running when it try's to connect to the database this is the error log i get

```
root@server:/etc/init.d# node /NodeJS/ChatServer/server.js
Server has started trying to connect to Database
Connection to Database has been made
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/NodeJS/ChatServer/node_modules/any-db-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:103:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/NodeJS/ChatServer/node_modules/any-db-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:102:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Comment: That's really not much information to go on.

Comment: this is the full server script http://hastebin.com/onohuyeqel.js

Comment: That's great, but what's the *minimal* non-functional example?

Comment: well the think is the server works fine on my pc and it runs on the vps but when a user try's to send a message it crashes  so i suppose it has to do with the insert part

Comment: You're going to have to do some diagnostics here. Creating a *minimal* example would be step #1 in my opinion. There is no obvious answer here.

Comment: i have found the issue the it losses the connection to the db so i need to add an function that reconects